# Does the phrase "at least in part" cover "exact match" too?

Tags: claims

```
wherein string A at least in part match with string B
```

Is the phrase "at least in part" here valid when both string A and String B has the exact same value?

Also is that phrase bi-directional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get an idea about this from an analogous [case](https://www.ipmvs.com/filewrapper-old/partially-does-not-include-totally-judgment-of-noninfringement-affirmed) involving "a portion" of the backing of a baby changing table. It was ruled that "a portion" did not include "the whole" and the alleged infringer won. Now we write "at least a portion" in our claims.